# How do Google Drive's shareable links react to toggling privileges?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets document that I've been sharing with colleagues for some time: it is essentially a Javascript application for parsing data.

In the past, I have simply passed access out using the Drive *shareable link* feature.

I have a coworker that would like to use the application for sensitive material. Nothing major, but we would not want previous users to be able to visit the link.

Now, I know I can turn off "anyone with the link" in the Shared Advanced Preferences, but I'm curious what happens if I turn this off and then back on? I'm hoping to "void" the previous links I have passed out, and then send a new one to my coworker.

In short, **how can I void previous shareable links without removing my access to the feature?** Additionally, can anyone recommend links to better understanding Google Drive security?

Comment: why not just make a copy for your collegue and give access only to him for this copy

Comment: I definitely can. That is a good suggestion. However, I am curious re: google sheets privileges. Its been surprisingly hard for me to track down an answer to this, which is strange given how many people count on Drive being secure.

Answer (score 0):

You can not turn off the *link* itself. What you can do is change the preference  of who can access with the link.

So basically if you change the permissions of the file it will be updated, but the link could even be the same. So you don't have to worry about people accessing the file after updating the share preferences.